# Comparing a Void* LinkedList Node with a String in C

Tags: c, linked-list

So I am having problem with comparing strings that is stored in the LinkedList. All the values in the linked list are stored as Void* but I am not quite sure how to compare void* with a string. I have tried using strcmp() but there was no luck. Can someone point me in the right direction. Thank you.

LinkedList Class:

```
 typedef struct MissileNode 
    {
        //It can store any data types 
        void* missile; 
        struct MissileNode* next;
    }missile_node_t;
```

Main Class:

```
 missile_node_t* current = missiles->head;
     //This totally prints perfectly 
     printf("Current Missile: %s\n\n", current->missile);

//This is where I am having issue, my comparsion is not working  
 if(strcmp((char*)current->missile),"Single") == 0)
        {
            printf("work");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("doest work");
        }

current = current-> next;
```

OUTPUT:

```
Current Missile: Single 

doesn't work
```

Comment: @Obamaself To find the problem see what will be outputted by printf( "%zu\n", strlen( current->missile ) );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is defined as `int strcmp (const char* str1, const char* str2);`.
So you need to provide two string arguments.

In your code you write:

```c
if(strcmp(current->missile),"Single") == 0)
```

So you're calling `strcmp(current->missile)` with only one argument. You probably meant `strcmp(current->missile, "Single")`.

If you're using a C compiler this should work without a cast. If you're using a C++ compiler you will need to use `strcmp(reinterpret_cast<char*>(current->missile), "Single")`